# Hiding div contents when value from webservice is null

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have the following spans and I want to display contents if the value from the webservice is empty. If values aren't empty, display the angular expressions which will display information loaded from the webservice. I'm using an ng-if statement in which "if" the service value is =='' then it simply returns the text from the span, but if the service value is !='' then it loads ({{user.PhoneNumbers[0].AreaCode}}). This is due to  when the service value is empty, the () still show on the display.

Here is what I'm working with

```
<span ng-if= "user.PhoneNumbers.AreaCode== ''">No Area Code Entered</span>
<span ng-if= "user.PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumber== ''">No Phone Number Entered</span>
<span ng-if="user.PhoneNumbers.AreaCode != ''">({{user.PhoneNumbers[0].AreaCode}}) {{user.PhoneNumbers[0].PhoneNumber | phonenumber}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you check should be

```
<span ng-if="!user.PhoneNumbers.AreaCode">
    ({{user.PhoneNumbers[0].AreaCode}}) {{user.PhoneNumbers[0].PhoneNumber | phonenumber}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few cases to consider:

- `ng-if="user.PhoneNumbers.length == 0"`: no phone numbers are entered at all
- `ng-if="user.PhoneNumbers.length > 0 && !user.PhoneNumbers[0].AreaCode"`: there is a phone entry, but it is missing an area code
- `ng-if="user.PhoneNumbers.length > 0 && !user.PhoneNumbers[0].PhoneNumber"`: there is a phone entry, but it is missing the primary number